# Finding Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree, euclidean-distance

Given a set of point $P$. Find the euclidean minimum spanning tree where each points is equally distributed on the plane using randomization.

We can solve this problem with Prim's algorithm in $O(n^2)$ which is too slow. I've found an algorithm called Delanuay Triangulation but is there any other ways to solve this problem in $O(n log n)$ or faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking this question because you want something easier to implement than a Delaunay triangulation algorithm you're most likely out of luck.

You should also specify in what space you're operating. If you're working with $\mathbb N^2$ coordinates, you can possibly do it in $\mathcal O(n \log\log n)$ (with a randomized algorithm to generate the triangulation).

If you have $P\in \mathbb R^2$ your choices (ordered by difficulty of implementation from easiest to not-easiest) are:

- Delaunay triangulation
- [WSPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-separated_pair_decomposition) based approaches (first find clusters on Quadtree of $P$, then build MSTs for each cluster and then connect clusters to get complete MST)
- Improved version of Boruvka's algorithm: [paper](https://mlpack.org/papers/emst.pdf)

The last one is also an improvement over the other two in higher dimensions. This answer is more or less a condensed version of the literature review of the linked paper.